# Custom Product Options per store view

Tags: magento-1.8, custom-options, store-view

I have a product with a custom option. I also have 2 store views, 1 being English & 1 being German.

When I set the price in the store view for English or German it doesn't update. However if I set the price in the "Default Values" store view then it updates but it obviously updates for both English and German.

Is this a bug with Magento as the admin allows me to untick default and enter a new price but doesn't save it?

Answer (score 1):

Magento has this for per website view inbuilt.

Go to

> System > Config > Catalog > Catalog > Price > Select 'Catalog Price
>   Scope' = Website

Then check-box will appear before price to make that different per website under Manage products.

Comment: Unfortunately I dont have different websites, I have different store views

Comment: There is one extension that will do the task for you google it , and you will found